# Pagination using Oracle database using JPA HIBERNATE Criteria

Tags: hibernate, spring-data-jpa, hibernate-criteria

I am trying to achieve pagination in my java program , below is the query which i am trying to write and not able to succeed using JPA, Criteria, hibernate.

SELECT rs.* from (select t.*, row_number() over (order by t.APPROVEDTIME desc) 
  as row_num  from Employee t ) rs where rs.row_num >= 1 
  and rs.row_num  < 10  order by rs.row_num

Comment: JPA works on entities where as SQL works on tables so unless you post your entity definition we cannot help you. Also please post what you have tried and what problems you faced. Refer to this [article](https://dzone.com/articles/spring-data-part-5-paging-and-sorting) for how to paginate using Spring Data JPA

Answer (score 0):

Information about pagination should be set on Query interface and not in SQL

```
List<Employee> employees = entityManager.createQuery("SELECT emp FROM Employee emp ORDER BY emp.id", Employee.class)
        .setMaxResults(10)
        .setFirstResult(0)
        .getResultList();
```